# React Native TextInput that Accepts a specific format only

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I need a textInput component for zip code that accepts only numeric values and satisfies the following format.

ZIP must be in `xxxxx-xxxx` or `xxxxx` format.

Note: character count should not exceed 10 (including hyphen `-`), character count can be either 10 or 5 only

Comment: You can try this library: https://github.com/CaioQuirinoMedeiros/react-native-mask-input

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best way here is to use react final form https://final-form.org/react library. You should use `format` and `validate` props of `<Field />`

Also check this example from their documentation. https://codesandbox.io/s/10rzowm323?file=/index.js